# Convert IEnumerable to List<string> in .net 2.0

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, ienumerable

I need to convert `IEnumerable` to a `List<string>`. one of the way is to itearte through this and add each object to a list but this process is vary time consuming. Is there any other way to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 20):

You can pass the enumerable directly into the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0.aspx) of a new `List<string>` instace:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>(yourEnumerable);
```

or you can use the [`AddRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx) method:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.AddRange(yourEnumerable);
```

This answer assumes that you in fact already have an `IEnumerable<string>`.
If this is not the case, your only option is a loop:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
foreach(object item in yourEnumerable)
    list.Add(item.ToString());
```

---

BTW: You are saying:

> one of the way is to itearte through this and add each object to a list but this process is vary time consuming

You need to iterate the enumerable in any case. How else would you get all values? In the first two sample codes I gave you, the enumeration is performed inside the `List<T>` class, but it is still happening.

Comment: Thanks for your help but i had IEnumerable this not IEnumerable <T> so i cannot used this method. Yes I know this also will iterate through it but it will take less time then doing it manually... as i am doing...

Comment: @user1685652: No, it will take just as much time. Why should it be any faster?

Comment: Sorry i didn't post the whole thing as i only want the way to convert this. for you i explain the whole process first need to convert it into a DirectoryEntry type object then to access it properties and then add this is taking much time.

Comment: @user1685652: But this has to happen at some time. It doesn't make it *slower* just because you wrote the loop!

Comment: In case of sorting if we use list.sort method it will perform the task faster then what we will do with iteration thats why i think that may be inbuild method will be better. Please tell me the way through which i can do this. As the method i am using is very time consuming and cann't be used. Thanks

Comment: @user1685652: Please understand that a loop won't be slower if it is written by you. There is nothing else to say. And without you showing your ***real*** code, I can't even tell you how your code might be implemented better. About the sort: The reason for this is that you are most likely use an algorithm that performs slower or you may have implemented it in a manner that is sub-optimal.